# How do I install RGoogleDocs from GitHub?

Tags: r, github, google-docs

I see that there is a new version of RGoogleDocs in GitHub. It is Version 0.6-0.
https://github.com/duncantl/RGoogleDocs.

How do I install it in the 64 bit version of R? In the past, Duncan Temple Lang provided pointed me to a zip file that contained the Windows binary file. I downloaded it and executed this command to get it installed

`install.packages("C:/Users/Farrel/Dropbox/RGoogleDocs_0.5-0.zip",repos=NULL)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `Rtools` installed, you can use the `devtools` package and its `install_github` function to directly install packages from `github`.

Answer (score 4):

For this particular package, you can click the button that says ZIP that is to the left of the git URL to download the zip file.  Then, unzip it into your working directory.  Or, you could use [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) to clone the code into a local directory.

Then, you can use `install.packages` with `type='source'`.

```
install.packages("duncantl-RGoogleDocs-0e3879c/", type='source', repos=NULL)
```

But, in general, it really would be a good idea to learn to build packages.

Answer (score 2):

See the [R on Windows FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Packages) about installing packages from source.